# Android: Extending and casting Fragment issue

Tags: android, fragment, pager

I am trying to create a ViewPager with several fragments following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iEl0ylVvZho). The problem is that Eclipse says that there is an error in the following statement:

```
Fragment f = new MyFragment();
```

But MyFragment extends the class Fragment so it's kind of weird to get errors like this. Here are the codes of `MyAdapter` and `MyFragment` classes:

```
package com.example.myapp;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

    public class MyFragment extends Fragment  {
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater li , ViewGroup vg , Bundle b) {
            return li.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, vg , false);            
        }       
        public MyFragment() {           
        }
    }

    class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {  
        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
            Fragment f = new MyFragment();
            return f;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }       
    }
```

Comment: What error do you get? Is it the same type of `Fragment`? (fragment vs support fragment)

Comment: it was a fragment/support fragment issue.  I have completely forgot about that . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the import:

```
import android.app.Fragment
```

To:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    Fragment f = new MyFragment();
    return f;
}
```

change to

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    MyFragment f = new MyFragment();
    return f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **viewpager** you need to use Fragment from support v4 package also. 
So you need to make sure MyFragment extends correct Fragment. As told by **nem** you need to change your import statement

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```